# Where do I save my preseed file on installation media? Ubuntu 14.04.4 Server 64 bit

Tags: system-installation, preseed

I am attempting to `preseed` a Ubuntu installation but all of the tutorials do not say where to save the preseed file to. They say to save it on the boot media and then pass the boot parameter `preseed/file` to indicate the location of the preseeding file. How to do do this?

Answer (score 1):

The root of the CD is /cdrom so for a preseed.cfg in the root must be:

```
file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg
```

Of course, you can create a folder for preseeds and change the path (ex. folder */responses*  will be file=/cdrom/responses/preseed.cfg)

For example I put a preseed file named xubuntu.cfg in the root of the CD and changed the 'append' option in *txt.cfg* with:

```
label live-install
  menu label ^Install Xubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append auto file=/cdrom/xubuntu.cfg keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us and console-setup/ask_detect=false boot=casper automatic-ubiquity noprompt initrd=/casper/initrd.lz ---
```

Comment: [B.2. Using Preseeding](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/apbs02.html.en) states "In this section, auto is thus not a parameter, it means selecting that boot choice, and appending the following boot parameters on the boot prompt". I understood that to mean that we are not supposed to write the word auto there. Would you happen to know more?

Comment: Yes. I use it to have a complete unattended installation source